# Javascript Regex Capture

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this:

```
var string = "apple:8080";
var reg = /\w*:(\d*)/;
console.log(reg.exec(string).toString());
```

produce this:

```
apple:8080,8080
```

All I want is `8080`.  I don't understand why `apple:` is being output at all.  I need to capture the number after a colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the group index number in-order to get the string stored in a particular index. By default `.exec` function spits out both matches and captures. So that you got, `apple:8080` match and `8080` capture.

```
> var string = "apple:8080";
> var reg = /\w*:(\d*)/;
> console.log(reg.exec(string)[1].toString());
8080
```

Update:

Add an extra while loop in-case of more than one substrings was matched.

```
var re = /\w*:(\d*)/g; 
var str = 'apple:8080 orange:8000';
var m;
while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
8080
8000
```

Comment: Ok, but what if the string has multiple "\w+:\d+" words.  How do I access the capture for each match?